# why does tcp-keep-alive affect the tcp-close in go?

Tags: tcp, go

I have a server, when accepting a connection, I set tcp-keep-alive  for 120seconds.But when I close the connection, acctually the connection doesn't close.by `netstat -anp | grep  9999`, I found the state was `ESTABLISHED` .And the client didn't receive any error from the socket , either. I want to know will tcp-keep-alive affect the tcp-close?

PS  go 1.4  centos

```
package main
import (
    "github.com/felixge/tcpkeepalive"
    "net"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)
func  Start() {
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", "127.0.0.1:9999")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for {
        conn, err := listener.AcceptTCP()
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        go handleClient(conn)
    }
}

func handleClient(conn *net.TCPConn) {
    kaConn, err := tcpkeepalive.EnableKeepAlive(conn)
    if err != nil {
    } else {
        kaConn.SetKeepAliveIdle(120 * time.Second)
        kaConn.SetKeepAliveCount(4)
        kaConn.SetKeepAliveInterval(5 * time.Second)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    conn.Close()
    return
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    Start()
}
```

Comment: In general it will not, I've not enough time to post a complete answer - however the tcpkeepalive library you are using is buggy and seems to duplicate and leak a file descriptor.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use that keepalive library. It duplicates file descriptors, and fails to close them.

If you need to set KeepAlive, use the methods provided in the net package.

- [SetKeepAlive](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetKeepAlive)
- [SetKeepAlivePeriod](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetKeepAlivePeriod)

You likely don't need any extra options set, but only if you're certain you do, then you can try to apply what's needed with the appropriate syscalls.

Comment: the keepalive library is not supposed to work on windows, are those methods supposed to work there?

Comment: @Hons, I have only linked to the std library. If you are referring to the package in the question, which I recommended not using, you can see in the README that it does not support windows.

Comment: I have a project that currently uses the keepalive library, but I'd need to make it work on windows as well, and if possibly remove unnecessary libraries. My question was related to the std library and if that settings work on windows as well.

Comment: Yes, the std library `net.TCPConn` methods work on windows.